# Using CoreData to save views in a Stack View

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, view

I have been looking into CoreData recently and some things have really confused me.

Firstly, I am planning to adapt core data to save some views in a stack view so that they can persist post-app closure; however, most of the tutorials online seem to focus on applying this system for a UITableView.

Secondly, I am using a very weird system to store my UIViews. I have an array that stores my custom UIView class, with each view having an additional NSObject that stores values (ex. name).

With the convoluted view array I am not sure where I can fit in an array of NSManagedObjects? Also how would I get the app to automatically remake the stack view every time the user opens the app again?

Comment: Don’t store views. Store data.

Comment: So would I have to store the data contained within each view, and reload the stack view every time the app restarts?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what you should do.